WinUI 3 - Programmatic Scroll to Virtualized Item in ItemsControl (not ListView)
I'm making a custom ItemsControl subclass with a fairly typical template:
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" /> 
                <!-- or VirtualizingStackPanel; not really sure 
                     why there are two different seemingly identical 
                     virtualization panels -->
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

where MyControl is a subclass of ItemsControl.
I need a way to programmatically scroll to an item, by content or even by index, that might not yet be realized on screen, where item heights are not uniform.
For ListView I can use ScrollIntoView but I don't want to derive from ListView as this comes with a lot of functionality I'm looking to replace/override.
In WPF VirtualizingStackPanel had BringIndexIntoViewPublic but that seems to be absent now and I can't find anything equivalent in WinUI VirtualizingStackPanel or ItemsStackPanel.
In the WinUI source code ListView.ScrollIntoView appears to be using a lot of internal/native functionality inside the ItemsPresenter that I can't access.
Is there any way to do this without subclassing ListView?

Have you tried the ItemsView control?
<ItemsView x:Name="ItemsViewControl" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" />

then in code-behind:
int targetIndex = 123;
this.ItemsViewControl.StartBringItemIntoView(targetIndex, new BringIntoViewOptions());


Oooh, that could work. Let me give it a shot and circle back.

Looks like I'd need to refactor due to several differences from ItemsControl . This is for a bespoke data grid, and a port from WPF, so I rely a lot on how ItemsControl works. But I like that this has an option for an animated scroll to, which even ListView doesn't. It could potentially be an even better workaround than ListView. Thanks for the tip.

Ok so ItemsView had a lot of stuff I didn't want either but that lead me to ItemsRepeater and that allowed me to start with a pretty generic control and get what I wanted. Although it still amounted to an obscene amount of trial and error that included subclassing ScrollView to make sticky columns. Long story. There are WAY too many controls in this framework that do almost-the-same-thing-but-not-quite and yet none of them actually does the union of all of them. But this works now so many thanks for steering me in the right direction.
